# Как удалить 1 TAB (отступ) в нескольких строках?

Tags: notepad++

Как добавить отступ понятно - выделяем, жмем ТАБ. А вот как также просто удалить 1 уровень отступ TAB?

Если такой функции нет, может есть плагин какой?

Comment: может `Shift` + `Tab`

Comment: Супер спасибо. Почему-то пробовал через Ctrl и Alt.

Answer (score 4):

Сочетание клавиш - <kbd>shift + tab</kbd>